# How to install Ubuntu Linux packages onto machine via usb flashdrive via terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, package-management, usb

I've installed Ubuntu Linux on an old iMac but only have keyboard access at the moment so I have to complete all networking operations via Terminal.

As far as I can tell I need to install net-tools to be able to connect to WI-FI but since I have no current internet connection (don't have an Ethernet cable on me) Terminal is unable to fetch the packages.

However I have a Chromebook with Linux enabled and a connection to the internet so was thinking I could install the packages onto a usb flashdrive then move the files into whatever the correct directory for net-tools would be as a workaround while I wait for my Ethernet cable to come in.

Is this possible? I'm a beginner to the Linux Terminal so I'm not sure if this is even necessary. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you still have the installer CD/DVD/USB drive that you used to install Ubuntu?   If so, you should be able to mount that and configure apt to use it, which will allow you to install net-tools.   if not, then I recommend downloading an ISO and making one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a android phone, connect USB to your Imac, then on the phone turn on data or turn on Wifi for connect to the Internet, then check usb cable details into your notifications, now just choose usb tethering into list, now your mac have Internet.